# Android - ViewPager is not showing the fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using a `tablayout` inside a fragemnt, the TabLayout has two fragments: one is showing a calendar and the other is just a simple plain text, I can switch between tabs correctly with out triggering any error, the problem is the content (inner fragments) are not showing, they are just "not there"!

- I tried looking into other threads on StackoverFlow that has the same issue, but most of them they are facing problems with NPEs (Null pointer exceptions) errors, which is not my case.
- I tried using: `getChildFragmentManager()` and `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`
- Please keep in mind that I am working with `Nested fragments`(fragments in a fragment)
- I am using the documentation of [AndroidHive](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) and I have used it before but with simple fragments not nested one, it works perfectly
- I tried using the Layout Inspector tool.

**Q:** What am I missing and what should I do to get it up and running?!

Here's my code so far:

**XML: MainFragment**

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabGravity="fill"/>
       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/viewpager"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
       </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML: Calendar fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    tools:context=".Tabs.CalendarTab">
    <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/compact_calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:compactCalendarTargetHeight="250dp"
        app:compactCalendarTextSize="12sp"
        app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:compactCalendarTextColor="@color/colorDarkGrey"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="@color/color13"
        app:compactCalendarMultiEventIndicatorColor="@color/textColor2"
        app:compactCalendarShouldSelectFirstDayOfMonthOnScroll="true"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentDayIndicatorStyle="fill_large_indicator"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML List fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Tabs.FullListTab">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="You Are In Tab 2"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainFragment JAVA**

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

//onCreate Method:
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
/*** end onCreate() ***/

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CalendarTab(), "Calendar");
    adapter.addFragment(new FullListTab(), "List");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using a third party library called `SPager` here's the [Github link](https://github.com/alfianyusufabdullah/spager) for full documentation. `SPager` does not use an adapter and it's easier and faster to implement.

> ***HOWEVER I AM STILL LOOKING FOR A ANOTHER WAY WITHOUT USING A THIRD PARTY LIBRARY***

This is what I practically did (as mentioned in their Github):

**Implementation**

```
implementation 'com.github.alfianyusufabdullah:spager:1.2.0'
```

**in the XML layout file**

```
<com.alfianyusufabdullah.SPager
   android:id="@+id/mPager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**in my JAVA class**

```
private SPager myViewPager;

//...

myViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.mPager);

//...

myViewPager.initFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager());
myViewPager.addPages("Inner fragment 1", new IFragOne());
myViewPager.addPages("Inner fragment 2", new IFragTwo());
myViewPager.build();
```

**IF** you are using a `tabLayout` you can bind it with `SPager` like so:

```
myViewPager.addTabLayout(tabLayout);
```

I should also mention that `SPager` is compatible with ***Kotlin***

> *I decided to post, it might be useful to others, for my case this is a temporary fix until, someone answers this thread!*

Comment: This was enough to fix my issue! I just submitted to `+50` reward! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> adapter.addFragment(new CalendarTab(), "Calendar");
> adapter.addFragment(new FullListTab(), "List");
>
> ...
>
> class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
>     private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

Don't do this, ***EVER***. It can lead to VERY cryptic bugs. You MUST return the new Fragment instance from inside `getItem()`, and not from elsewhere.

---

---

As for your actual question,

> ```
> XML: MainFragment
>
> <LinearLayout
>    android:orientation="vertical"
>    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
> ```

Change this to `match_parent`, `match_parent`.

Comment: I am using something like your answer.
`ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager();
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentHistory(), "");
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentBookmark(), "");
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentSettings(), "");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);`.
Why you said **to never do this**, which is the another way to achieve that ?

Comment: @Spritzig If you do that, you will have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753099/app-crash-after-activity-has-been-killed-in-background/55754360#55754360 (but you can also find same problem in https://stackoverflow.com/q/53978606/2413303 )

Comment: @EpicPandaForce for the first part, thank you for the informative tip, I'll work on improving it! but changing the width and height to `match_parent` didn't solve it, it's like the views visibility is set to `Gone` there's nothing there except the tab titles!! also, are you keeping in mind that all of this is inside another parent fragment ?

Comment: That it is in another parent fragment should already be solved by using `getChildFragmentManager()`. This sounds like layout size problem. However it wasn't what I thought it would be, so you might want to consider using `Layout Inspector` tool to see which of your views has a `0,0` size instead of something you actually expect.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you for the tips but for the moment it has been more than a year I use `java` and I have added `fragment` for `viewpager` like comment above and I didn't have any crash or something but I will check your answers there and get which is the best approach again thanks.
If do you have time please check for my last question I need an answer there.

Comment: @Spritzig this comes up in an evident way only if you test for this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I used Layout Inspector, great tool, it just gave me a lot of readings, but the fragments are still not showing in the graphic representation

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am facing a problem, can you please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324415/realm-greater-than-query-on-a-string-value thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this in the past. I solved it by nesting the `TabLayout` in the `ViewPager`, as seen [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#viewpager-integration):

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabGravity="fill"/>

  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What? No you don't

Comment: I had this problem a few weeks ago, and solved it by nesting the TabLayout. Unless it was another bug that got "fixed" by doing this :P anyway, I followed the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#viewpager-integration

Comment: Hmm, `as part of a ViewPager's decor`.. I wonder what that means. But yeah, apparently you *can* put it inside a ViewPager. I don't think you have to, though. It works even if it isn't.

Comment: Yeah, I was not nesting it to begin with, as most examples online don't as well. I didn't understand the "decor" part too, but I tried to nest it and it fixed my problem. My problem was similar to the one OP has, and hence the "You have to nest". I guess I'll edit the answer to be more clear.

Comment: @RicardoCosteira probably that's not the problem, I tried it but no luck